# Setting a variable as a function call to use in an if statement within PHP

Tags: php

Ok, so am doing some Wordpress edits, and I writ a if statement.

```
<?php $title = the_title();
if ($title != 'Designer'){ ?>
<body>
<?php }else{ ?>
<body class="noresponce">
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see though, this uses a function call as a variable. This is because the function call will call the name of the current page. This is good.

However it also tends to echo the title on page as well when I do this, which makes sense. I may be trying to do something that isn't correct. Can anyone tell me if its possible though?

Basically I want to use the function call in an if statement without it being echoed on page.

Comment: side note: you've misspelled "responce"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()`.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: Legend, simple effective answers always make my day. Thank you.